# MongoDb/C# poor concurrent read performance

Tags: performance, mongodb

I'm testing a few NoSQL solution and I'm focusing mainly on read performance. Today was MongoDb day.
The test machine is a VM with a Quad Core Xeon @2.93GHz and 8GB of RAM.

I'm testing with only database and a single collection with ~100.000 documents. The BSON document size is around 20Kb, more or less.

The managed object I'm working with is:

```
private class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<string> Industries { get; set; }
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The test process:

-Create 100 threads.

-Start all threads.

-Each thread reads 20 random documents from the collection.

Here's the select method I'm using:

```
private static void TestSelectWithCursor(object state)
{
    resetEvent.WaitOne();

    MongoCollection jobs = (state as MongoCollection);
    var q = jobs.AsQueryable<Job>();
    Random r = new Random(938432094);
    List<int> ids = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i != 20; ++i)
    {
        ids.Add(r.Next(1000, 100000));
    }
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var subset = from j in q
                 where j.Id.In(ids)
                 select j;

    int count = 0;
    foreach (Job job in subset)
    {
        count++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Retrieved {0} documents in {1} ms.", count, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    ThreadsCount++;
}
```

The "count++" stuff is just to pretend I'm doing something after retrieving the cursor, so please ignore that.

Anyway, the idea is that I get what seems to me to be very slow read times. This is a typical test result:

```
> 100 threads created.
> 
> Retrieved 20 documents in 272 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 522 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 681 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 732 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 769 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 843 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1038 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1139 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1163 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1170 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1206 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1243 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1322 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1378 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1463 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1507 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1530 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1557 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1567 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1617 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1626 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1659 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1666 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1687 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1711 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1731 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1763 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1839 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1854 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1887 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1906 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1946 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1962 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1967 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1969 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 1977 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 1996 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2005 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2009 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2025 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2035 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2066 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2093 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2111 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2133 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2147 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2150 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2152 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2155 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2160 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2166 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2196 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2202 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2254 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2256 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2262 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2263 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2285 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2326 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2336 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2337 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2350 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2372 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2384 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2412 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2426 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2457 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2473 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2521 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2528 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2604 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2659 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2670 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 2687 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 2961 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3234 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3434 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3440 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3452 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3466 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3502 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3524 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3561 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3611 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3652 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3655 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3666 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3711 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3742 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 3821 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 3850 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 4020 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 5143 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 6607 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 6630 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 6633 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 6637 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 6639 ms.
> Retrieved 20 documents in 6801 ms. Retrieved 20 documents in 9302 ms.
```

The bottom line is that I was expecting to get much faster read times than this. I'm still thinking I'm doing something wrong.
Not sure what other information I can provide now, but if anything is missed then please let me know.

I am also including, hoping that it'll help, the explain() trace on one of the queries that is executed by the test:

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_ multi",
        "nscanned" : 39,
        "nscannedObjects" : 20,
        "n" : 20,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [
                        [
                                3276,
                                3276
                        ],
                        [
                                8257,
                                8257
                        ],
                        [
                                11189,
                                11189
                        ],
                        [
                                21779,
                                21779
                        ],
                        [
                                22293,
                                22293
                        ],
                        [
                                23376,
                                23376
                        ],
                        [
                                28656,
                                28656
                        ],
                        [
                                29557,
                                29557
                        ],
                        [
                                32160,
                                32160
                        ],
                        [
                                34833,
                                34833
                        ],
                        [
                                35922,
                                35922
                        ],
                        [
                                39141,
                                39141
                        ],
                        [
                                49094,
                                49094
                        ],
                        [
                                54554,
                                54554
                        ],
                        [
                                67684,
                                67684
                        ],
                        [
                                76384,
                                76384
                        ],
                        [
                                85612,
                                85612
                        ],
                        [
                                85838,
                                85838
                        ],
                        [
                                91634,
                                91634
                        ],
                        [
                                99891,
                                99891
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

If you have any idea, then I'll be most anxious to read it.
Thank you in advance!

Marcel

Comment: Well, no luck so far... Any fresh ideas?

Comment: Hi marceln, I am taking a look.  Just for thoroughness, you mentioned you were testing some others as well.  Have you run this test against those and experienced different results?

Comment: I'm trying to stick with Mongo. I've tested RavenDb, but it is way too slow. I've also tested CouchDb briefly, which seems even slower. Anyway, I would like to use MongoDb because the others have only a REST interface, which is not as fast as Mongo's binary protocol (I think).

Comment: I replied here if you could go take a look at the attached files: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/hi2wnH7sgSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the "in" (Generic Modifier) is forcing a sequential scan with full extraction of each document to check the where clause, bypassing the efficiency of using the _id index. Given that the random numbers can be quite distributed, my guess is that each thread/query is scanning essentially the full database.

I suggest trying a couple of things.
(1) Query individually for each of the 20 docs by individual single id
(2) Consider using a MongoCursor and use Explain to get information about index use for your query

Blessings,

-Gary

P.S. The thread times seem to indicate that there are also some thread scheduling effects at work.

Comment: Thanks Gary! However, retrieving each document individually has not improved the results. The explain() output for the In clause is above. As you can see, one thread does not cause the entire database to be scanned (nscanned is very low). But I think you were right that having lots of threads accessing random documents will cause the database to be scanned anyway. Not all at once, but 100 times in smaller amounts. I will also try the MongoDb forum.